# MutationObserver not firing as expected

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I have a textarea.

```
<textarea id="textarea"> </textarea>
```

I have the following Mutation Observer set up to watch for any text changes in the textarea.

```js
const targetNode = document.getElementById('textarea');
const options = {
  subtree: true,
  characterData: true,
};
const obs = new MutationObserver(function(mutationsList, observer) {
  console.log('mutationsList', mutationsList);
});
obs.observe(targetNode, options);
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea"> </textarea>
```

On typing into the textarea, I would expect some sort of console output. But nothing is coming through. What am I missing here?

(Yes I realize this is an extremely contrived example, and that I could have simply listened to an `onChange` event; I'm just trying to get my feet wet with MutationObservers here)

Comment: Typing into an input field doesn't change the DOM.

Comment: MutationObserver is for detecting structural changes to the DOM.

Comment: To add a finer point to Barmar's comment: _why_ would you expect it to do something? Because the docs may be a bit dense, but they definitely don't suggest this would ever work.

Comment: As a sidenote, entering text in an input **does** change the DOM - but it's an internal shadow DOM you cannot access for built-in elements like`input` and `textarea`. You can see it if you enable the corresponding setting in Chrome's dev tools.